# Connecting to flask docker container on windows browser

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have docker running on my Windows 10 OS and I have a minimal flask app

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
  
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host ='0.0.0.0', port = 5001, debug = True)
```

And I am dockerizing it using the following file

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
COPY . /opt
WORKDIR /opt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5001
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD ["app.py", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

From what I am seeing on other posts and on Flask tutorials having a `0.0.0.0` should allow me to connect from the windows firefox browser when I type `0.0.0.0:5001` but it is not connecting, I keep getting a 'unable to connect' message. I remember using the `0.0.0.0:port` to connect in localhost on a linux ubuntu machine but for whatever reason its not letting me connect on Windows. Is there a special setting to connect on windows ?

Comment: How are you starting the container?  0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address meaning "everywhere"; you need to listen to "everywhere" to accept connections from outside the container, but it doesn't make sense to connect to "everywhere" or include 0.0.0.0 in a URL.

Comment: Don't connect to 0.0.0.0:5001 in your browser, connect to 127.0.0.1:5001

Comment: Thanks @jbabtieu, I finally got it to work. The resolution was to have docker start at 0.0.0.0:5001 but on chrome browser in windows use 127.0.0.1:5001 to reach the site. I was getting confused as in linux you would just have docker start at 0.0.0.0:5001 and also try in a browser in linux on 0.0.0.0:5001

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Docker container, the *private* port is **5001**. This private port then needs to be mapped to a *public* port when running the container. For example, to set the public port to **8000**, you could run:

```sh
$ docker run --publish 8000:5001 --name <docker-container> <docker-container>:<version-tag>
```

The Flask app would then be accessible at URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000

### Dockerfile

In addition, since in **app.py** you are setting the host and port, there is no need to specify these values in the Dockerfile `CMD`. But the public port (in this example **8000**) needs to be exposed.

It also looks like the `COPY` command is placing everything under an `/opt` directory, so that needs to be included in the app path when launching the Flask app within Docker.

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
COPY . /opt
WORKDIR /opt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "/opt/app.py"]
```

### Docker-Flask Example

For a complete Flask-Docker example, including using Gunicorn, see:

[**Docker Python Flask Example using the Gunicorn WSGI HTTP Server**](https://github.com/cpeisert/docker-python-example)